# addIdentity in JSch is private key of calling program's Server

Tags: java, ssh, public-key-encryption, jsch, private-key

"Server 1" is reading from and writing to "Server 2" using SSH.

- "Server 1" is having "Server 1's" private key and public key of "Server 2".
- "Server 2" is having "Server 2's" private key and public key of "Server 1".

In JSch, when I use a Java program to communicate from "Server 1" to "Server 2", the program is using `addIdentity` method. This method is using "Server 1's" private key and JSch will not send this to anybody ("Server 2"), am I right?

Am confused with mentioning private key in this in `addIdentity` method. If possible please give me some JSch related doc which enlighten me more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

The `.addIdentity` is used to specify what private key should be used to locally encrypt the data before sending them to the remote server (and to decrypt the incoming data). The private key itself is not sent anywhere. Only a public key is.

Note that the `.addIdentity` loads a key pair (both the public and the private key). Even if you use an overload that takes `prvkey` path only, the JSch assumes that the public key file has the same name, just `.pub` extension; or that the "private key" file actually contains both public and private key.

---

For details, read about [Public-key/asymmetric cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).

---

*Though note that the key is a private key of the account you are connecting with to the remote server. It's not (should not be) a private key of the local machine (even if the machine happens to be a [SSH] server).*

Comment: ,Thanks for your reply.But  single private key can be used by many users in a server If they have access to that file , am I right ?

Comment: It can, but it's not common usage. The private key should be private. Once many users have access to the key, no one can be sure if the other users didn't compromise the key. It's as insecure as sharing a password.